# Witten anomaly and bound states of fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, research-level, quantum-anomalies, non-perturbative

In his famous paper ["An SU(2) anomaly"](https://inspirehep.net/literature/181968), Witten begins by noting that an SU(2) gauge theory with a single fermion in the doublet representation is weird, since there is "no obvious attractive channel in which a fermion condensate could form, consistent with Fermi statistics and Lorentz invariance".

Let $\psi_{ai}$ be the fermion, with $a=1,2$ an $SU(2)_L$ Lorentz index and $i=1,2$ an $SU(2)$ gauge index. The following operator
$$
\psi_{ai}\psi_{bj}\psi_{ck}\psi_{d\ell}\epsilon_{ab}\epsilon_{cd}\epsilon_{ik}\epsilon_{j\ell}
$$
seems to be a non-trivial, Lorentz-and-gauge-scalar consistent with fermi statistics. So I would say it could be the channel for a fermion condensate, contradicting Witten's claim. Obviously, Witten is right and I am wrong -- but what exactly is wrong with this condensate?

NB. If we write a pair of $SU(2)_L\times SU(2)$ indices as a vector index of $SO(4)$, then the condensate is $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\psi_\mu\psi_\nu\psi_\rho\psi_\sigma$, which makes it even more manifest that this is a scalar under both Lorentz and gauge, it is totally anti-symmetric, and real (reality seems irrelevant here though).

Comment: is perhaps the point that we do *not* want the condensate to be a gauge singlet? In that case, wouldn't $\psi_{ai}\psi_{bj}\epsilon_{ab}$ do the trick?